# How to do a 5x5 system using Cramer's rule?

Tags: function-construction

I need to know how to do a 5x5 system using Cramer's rule.

Comment: Are you on the correct site? This is for Mathematica software. Maybe you are looking for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions. Also see this [*write up*](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Matrices-and-determiminant/Matrices-and-determiminant.faq.question.962819.html)

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please browse through the `Applications` sections on the doc page for [`Det`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Det.html).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about the computing software Mathematica (it is a mathematics question) and as it's written shouldn't be migrated to Mathematics.SE.

Answer (score 2):

With Mathematica this can be done as follows. First, we construct a matrix of coefficients and
an RHS vector by

```
m = Array[a, {5, 5}]; k=Array[b, 5];
```

For example, in order to calculate $x_2$ we replace the second column of `m` by `k` through

```
ReplacePart[m, {j_, 2} -> k[[j]]];
```

BTW, I don't understand why a warning "Part::pkspec1: The expression j cannot be used as a part specification." is produced. At last, we find $x_2$ by

```
Det[ReplacePart[m, {j_, 2} -> k[[j]]]]/Det[m]
```

The huge output is of theoretical interest only. In practice, other method are used to this end.